# AIX- Does not install shared lib

Tags: installation, shared-libraries, aix

I am able to build the shared object successfully using the holy native compiler "xlc" on AIX.It does build the shared object library but does not install the shared object library.

Configure command is:
./configure --prefix=/PATH/to/install --exec-prefix=/PATH/to/install --enable-shared --enable-static=no --enable-module=so --build=powerpc-ibm-aix5.3.0.0 --host=powerpc-ibm-aix5.3.0.0 LDFLAGS="-G -shared"

Any help would be appreciated?

Answer (score 0):

So you are trying to compile to the shared library location.

I would suggest seeing if you can compile/link to your local directory.

If that works, try copying the new library to the correct directory.   It may be that the oldshared library is open by some process and therefore can't be overwritten.

Are you getting any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

I could install the shared library successfully when i had to exclusively export LDFLAGS as "-brtl -L/path/to/install".

Comment: ya, that strips the path off the name.

Answer (score 0):

Under AIX, there are two types of shared libraries, AIX style, and SysV compat libs.

AIX style libs are archvies that can contain static libraries as well as multiple versions of shared libraries, and have names like libFOO.a

SysV-compat libs have names like libFoo.so and are more like what you would find on Linux.

Libtool will build either type.  If you want SysV-compat libs, add -Wl,-brtl to LDFLAGS.

My guess is that you see /PATH/to/install/lib/libFOO.a and are assuming that it's a static library, when in fact, it's an AIX shared library.