# Linking against a shared library on AIX

Tags: c, gcc, linker, aix, apr

I'm trying to link against a shared library (apr) on AIX 5.3 using gcc/libtool.

The output from the compiler is as follows (with some irrelevant flags removed for the sake of simplicity):

```
libtool: link: gcc  -o test test.o  -L/opt/freeware/lib -lapr-1 -lpthread -Wl,-blibpath:/opt/freeware lib:/usr/lib:/lib
```

Then I checked what shared libs the resulting binary uses:

```
$ ldd test 
test needs:
     /usr/lib/libc.a(shr.o)
     /usr/lib/libpthread.a(shr_xpg5.o)
     /unix
     /usr/lib/libcrypt.a(shr.o)
     /usr/lib/libpthreads.a(shr_comm.o)
```

Notice that 'libapr-1' is missing here, though the symbols are there in the binary (verified with nm), which suggests that it is linked in statically.

This wouldn't be such a big problem for simple programs. Unfortunately my code in question uses dynamically loadable modules. The main program calls apr_initialize which sets a static variable 'apr_pools_initialized' inside the library. The loadable modules then try to use apr_pool_create which first check whether the initialization has been performed. Since they have their own statically linked apr, the static variable 'apr_pools_initialized' is not at the same memory location what the main program initialized. This makes the statically linked binary non-functional.

The apr library is installed using a precompiled binary rpm (apr and apr-devel). The relevant library files are there:

```
# rpm -ql apr|grep \\.so$
/opt/freeware/lib/libapr-1.so
/opt/freeware/lib64/libapr-1.so
/usr/lib/libapr-1.so

# rpm -ql apr-devel|grep \\.a$
/opt/freeware/lib/libapr-1.a
/opt/freeware/lib64/libapr-1.a
/usr/lib/libapr-1.a
/usr/lib64/libapr-1.a
/usr/lib64/libapr-1.so
```

I tried to remove the '.a' files hoping that the linker would have no choice but to use the '.so' and link it dynamically, unfortunately AIX is different and this does not work.
Regarding this topic I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1580472/aix-does-not-install-shared-lib/13091921#13091921) answer and [another libtool question](http://www.mail-archive.com/libtool@gnu.org/msg12995.html) which give some insight.

The question is: **How can I link this to my binary dynamically?**

Comment: there are a lot of AIX people in a special group on http://it.toolbox.com/groups/. Simple registration required. (I have no financial interests there). Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the links referenced contained the solution to this problem, which is:

```
-Wl,-brtl
```

Adding these LDFLAGS solved the linking problem.